# How can we specific an Activity to use dialog theme, if our Application already using a custom theme

Tags: android

Currently, our application has a very own custom theme

```
// AndroidManifest.xml
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.JStock.Light.DarkActionBar" >

    <activity android:name="org.yccheok.jstock.gui.billing.ShopDialogFragmentActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />

</application>


// themes.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.JStock.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="watchlistLinearLayoutHeaderBackground">@color/watchlist_linear_layout_header_background_inverse_holo_light</item>
        ....
        <item name="homeMenuBackground">@color/home_menu_background_inverse_holo_light</item>
    </style>
</resource>
```

In order to make `ShopDialogFragmentActivity` looks like a dialog, I try to use

```
    <activity android:name="org.yccheok.jstock.gui.billing.ShopDialogFragmentActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

However, this will create a problem.

Layout file used by `ShopDialogFragmentActivity`, can no longer have access to the attributes defined in `Theme.JStock.Light.DarkActionBar`.

For instance, `watchlistLinearLayoutHeaderBackground` and `homeMenuBackground` no longer visible to `ShopDialogFragmentActivity`, if it were using `@android:style/Theme.Dialog`

My guess is, the theme `@android:style/Theme.Dialog` had completely overwrite `Theme.JStock.Light.DarkActionBar`. All attributes defined in `Theme.JStock.Light.DarkActionBar` are no longer visible to `Activity` which is using different theme from `Application`.

I was wondering, what is the elegant way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Make your custom style with **parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog"**

```
<style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: The question is not about windowNoTitle. The question is, how to access application custom theme, if the activity wants to use another theme.